# Display FadeItems in <div> next to each other

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="navigation_desktop">

        <div class="button_desktop_01">1.0 Main Menu
            <div class="FadeItem_01">
                <div>1.1 Sub Menu </div>
                <div class="button_desktop_02">1.2 Sub Menu
                    <div class="FadeItem_02">
                        <div>
                            <div>1.2.1 Sub Menu</div>
                            <div>1.2.2 Sub Menu</div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button_desktop_01">2.0 Main Menu
            <div class="FadeItem_01">
                <div class="button_desktop_02">2.1 Sub Menu
                    <div class="FadeItem_02">
                        <div>
                            <div>2.1.1 Sub Menu</div>
                            <div>2.1.2 Sub Menu</div>
                            <div>2.1.3 Sub Menu</div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div>2.2 Sub Menu</div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .button_desktop_01{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #5882FA
 }

 .button_desktop_02 {
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02 {
 display: none;
}

.FadeItem_02 {
 float: left;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

The code above **FadeIn/Out** some FadeItems which works perfectly so far.
Now I want that the `<div class="FadeItem_02">` appears **right next** to the `<div class="FadeItem_01">`.

I tried to do this wiht the `float: left;` property on the class `.FadeItem_02` but it does no work.

How do I have to modify my code to achieve this?
Ideally, it should appear in the **exact same style** *(size, colour, etc.)* as it does now but instead of appearing *below* the `<div class="FadeItem_01">` it should **appear right next to it**.

You can also find all codes here: https://jsfiddle.net/gycp99zj/6/

Comment: What !!? you jsfiddle does exactly what you said you could not do...Both div are right next to each other

Comment: No. The FadeItem_02 (1.2.1 Sub Menu & 1.2.2 Sub Menu) appears below FadeItem_01 (1.2 Sub Menu) but I want it to appear right next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these settings:

```
 .button_desktop_02 {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
 }

 .FadeItem_01,
 .FadeItem_02 {
   display: none;
 }

 .FadeItem_01 {
   position: relative;
 }

 .FadeItem_02 {
   position: absolute;
   left: 120px;
   top: 0;
   width: 120px;
   background: #5882FA
 }
```

The absolute positioning takes the sub-submenu out of the submenu, the relative  position of their parent acts as an "anchor", the position settings (top, left) determine where they appear, and it also needs a width.

That code in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avc7pr8a/1/

Comment: Using percentages 100% at left and width makes it look better

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
.FadeItem_02 {
  position:relative;
  left:100%;
  background: #5882FA
}
```

Comment: Looks good but how can I get rid of the space and connect to the same height of FadeItem_01?

Answer (score 0):

Did you meant?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
 .button_desktop_01{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #5882FA
 }

 .button_desktop_02 {
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02 {
 display: none;
}
.FadeItem_02 {
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  background: #5882FA
}

.button_desktop_02 {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
 }

 .FadeItem_01,
 .FadeItem_02 {
   display: none;
 }

 .FadeItem_01 {
   position: relative;
 }

 .FadeItem_02 {
   position: absolute;
   left: 110px;
   top: 0;
   width: 120px;
   background: #5882FA
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="navigation_desktop">

        <div class="button_desktop_01">1.0 Main Menu
            <div class="FadeItem_01">
                <div>1.1 Sub Menu </div>
                <div class="button_desktop_02">1.2 Sub Menu
                    <div class="FadeItem_02">
                        <div>
                            <div>1.2.1 Sub Menu</div>
                            <div>1.2.2 Sub Menu</div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button_desktop_01">2.0 Main Menu
            <div class="FadeItem_01">
                <div class="button_desktop_02">2.1 Sub Menu
                    <div class="FadeItem_02">
                        <div>
                            <div>2.1.1 Sub Menu</div>
                            <div>2.1.2 Sub Menu</div>
                            <div>2.1.3 Sub Menu</div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div>2.2 Sub Menu</div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```